# How to get workboxPlugin.InjectManifest to work with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I followed the steps at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers but the `dist/sw.js` file after being built was not processed by Webpack at all.  All the import statements are still there left untouched, comments are not being stripped out, and not uglify at all by Terser.

What did I do wrong? Should `sw.js` be first built as a separate entry and then pass the output to the plugin?

dist/sw.js (actual output, nothing is being processed other than the first line got injected)

```
importScripts("/dist/precache-manifest.f26179340acee9ac29fc6c689e5cb0c5.js", "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

/* global clients */

import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing'
import { CacheFirst, NetworkFirst } from 'workbox-strategies'
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies'
import { setConfig, skipWaiting, clientsClaim } from 'workbox-sw'
import { Plugin as BroadcastUpdatePlugin } from 'workbox-broadcast-update'
import { Plugin as ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration'
import { Plugin as CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response'
```

./src/sw.js

```
/* global clients */

import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing'
import { CacheFirst, NetworkFirst } from 'workbox-strategies'
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies'
import { setConfig, skipWaiting, clientsClaim } from 'workbox-sw'
import { Plugin as BroadcastUpdatePlugin } from 'workbox-broadcast-update'
import { Plugin as ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration'
import { Plugin as CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response'
```

webpack.common.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new workboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
            swSrc: './src/sw.js',
            swDest: 'sw.js'
        })
    ]
}
```

webpack.prod.config.js

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
    stats: {
        chunkModules: true,
        // Examine all modules
        maxModules: Infinity,
        // Display bailout reasons
        optimizationBailout: false
    },
    plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin({ verbose: true })],
    optimization: {
        // Use terser instead of the default Uglify since service
        // worker code does not need to be transpiled to ES5.
        minimizer: [
            new Terser({
                // Ensure .mjs files get included.
                test: /\.m?js$/
            })
        ]
    }
})
```

Related issue on Github: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We are actively working on a rewrite for the InjectManifest plugin that will perform a webpack child compilation on swSrc, in addition to populate the precache manifest.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1513#issuecomment-506482323